# Calling a function inside a function in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to access the function inside a function in Node js. Below is my one.js: -

```
module.exports.user1 = ()=>{

    updateNewUser:(req,res,next)=>{
        console.log("User1")
    }

}
module.exports.user2 = ()=>{

    updateNewUser:(req,res,next)=>{
        console.log("User2")
    }

}
```

and I am calling the function in two.js: -

```
var one = require('one.js');
console.log(one.user1.updateNewUser)
```

I want to access updateNewUser in one.js.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `user1` is a *function* which **when called** returns an object which has a property `updateNewUser` which is a function. (At least if you specified it correctly, as it it won't return anything…) Does that help…?

Comment: @deceze so what would be the syntax to call the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module.exports = {
    user1: {
        updateNewUser: (req, res, next) => {
            console.log("User1")
        }
    },
    user2: {
        updateNewUser: (req, res, next) => {
            console.log("User2")
        }
    }
}

const one = require('./one.js')
one.user1.updateNewUser(<p1>, <p2>, <p3>)
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vrz6t8?file=one.js

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change your `one.js` to:

```
module.exports = {
    user1: (req, res, next) => {
        console.log("User1")
    },
    user2: (req, res, next) => {
        console.log("User2")
    }
};
```

And in `two.js`:

```
let one = require('./one');

one.user1(); //Outputs: User1
one.user2(); //Outputs: User2
```

This is cleaner, but if you really want a function inside a function, then:

```
module.exports = {
    user1: () => {
        return (req, res, next) => { // Added return
            console.log("User1")
        }
    },
    user2: () => {
        return (req, res, next) => { // Added return
            console.log("User2")
        }
    }
};
```

**NOTE:** I added a `return` keyword so we can access the inner function, and that is one thing that you are missing in your `one.js`

And you call it in `two.js` with:

```
let one = require('./one');

one.user1()(); //Outputs: User1
one.user2()(); //Outputs: User2
```

Comment: In your case ,I wont be able to call more than one function in user1